# BIOS settings in Asus X451C

Tags: bios, asus-laptop, setup

why my notebook x451c can't enter in BIOS settings ? I use f2,f8,f10,f12,ESC,del, FN+f2,f2+del And nothing can to fixed.
Please, help me.

Comment: Usually during the splash screen it will tell you exactly why keys need to be pressed.  Does yours say anything?  I believe my Asus motherboard accepts `Delete` as one of my options...

Comment: this morning i was tried to press the F2 button and hold it, then press the power button, but dont release F2 button until BIOS setting is come out.. and tha's worked... Thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

According to the User Manual found at the link below (pg 70), "Restart your Notebook PC then press <kbd>F2</kbd> during POST" to access BIOS.

https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X451CA/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark as accepted